Automate the SSL certificate selection in chrome with selenium web driver (python)
I'm working with python selenium to collect data on a web page automatically.
When I try to get the page a popup appears asking to select SSL certificate.
Then my automation is broken because I need to click the 'OK' button to select the certificate every time I want to launch the program.
Select certificate popup
I want my program to select automatically the certificate (there is only one) and continue.
Or maybe it is possible to make the browser automatically use this certificate for this specific site ?
Actually I use a non-optimal solution with PyAutoGUI : I launch another thread before getting the page, this other thread waits 7 seconds to let the popup appears, then press 2 times 'tab' key to navigate toward the 'OK' button and finally press 'enter' key to select the certificate. Here is the actual code for this :
import threading
import pyautogui
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


def getPage():
  capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
  capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}
  path = chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
  service = Service(executable_path=path)
  #Initializing chrome options
  options_chrome = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options_chrome.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options_chrome.set_capability('cloud:options', capabilities)
  options_chrome.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
  options_chrome.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
  options_chrome.add_argument('--disable-search-engine-choice-screen')
  options_chrome.add_argument('--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests')
  options_chrome.add_argument("--log-level=1")
  
  #NON-OPTIMAL solution with multithreading
  t2 = threading.Thread(target=PressEnter)
  t2.daemon = True
  t2.start()
  
  #Getting the page
  chrome_driver.get("https://myUrl.com/myPage")

def pressEnter():
  #Wait 7 seconds to let the popup appears
  time.sleep(7)

  #Use PyAutoGUI to interact with the popup
  print("cliquing")
  #Naviguate to the 'OK' button
  pyautogui.press('tab')
  pyautogui.press('tab')
  #Press <enter>
  pyautogui.press('enter')
  print("clicked !")


I've tried to add the option : options_chrome.add_argument('--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests'),
but didn't worked, the popup still blocks the execution.
I've tried to export the certificate and add it as an option :
options_chrome.add_argument("--ssl-client-certificate-file=C:\my_path\to\certificat.p7b"),
still didn't work.
I have to mention that the automation worked before a recent Chrome update and the popup hasn't blocked the execution until this update.
This recent update has brought the research engine choice page on chrome which I have disabled with the option : options_chrome.add_argument('--disable-search-engine-choice-screen').
From this moment, the certificate popup started to block the execution.

Use Chrome AutoSelectCertificateForUrls Policy
You can configure Chrome to automatically select a certificate for a specific domain by passing a Chrome policy through the AutoSelectCertificateForUrls preference.
This requires setting up a JSON policy that tells Chrome to auto-select the certificate for a specific site. Here’s how:
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
import json

def getPage():
    path = chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
    service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(executable_path=path)
    
    # Initialize Chrome options
    options_chrome = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    
    # JSON policy for auto-selecting SSL certificates
    auto_select_cert = {
        "pattern": "https://myUrl.com/*",
        "filter": {
            "ISSUER": {"CN": "The SSL certificate issuer"}
        }
    }
    
    # Pass the certificate policy to Chrome
    options_chrome.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
        "ssl": {
            "auto_select_certificate_for_urls": [auto_select_cert]
        }
    })
    
    # Ignore SSL certificate errors
    options_chrome.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
    options_chrome.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

    # Initialize the Chrome driver with options
    chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options_chrome)

    # Get the page
    chrome_driver.get("https://myUrl.com/myPage")

getPage()


Make sure to update the ISSUER with the correct certificate issuer information.
